# Почему при работе RUN npm install возникает ошибка?

Tags: docker

Начал изучение `docker` - делаю все по [инструкции](https://docs.docker.com/guides/walkthroughs/run-a-container/) из документации, но на шаге 3 при выполнении команды `sudo docker build -t welcome-to-docker .` возникает ошибка

```
 > [6/6] RUN npm install     && npm install -g serve     && npm run build     && rm -fr node_modules:                                                         
55.05 npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.                                         
75.16 npm notice                                                                                                                                              
75.16 npm notice New patch version of npm available! 10.2.3 -> 10.2.4                                                                                         
75.16 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.2.4>                                                                                 
75.16 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.2.4` to update!
75.16 npm notice 
75.16 npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
75.16 npm ERR! syscall read
75.16 npm ERR! errno -110
75.16 npm ERR! network read ETIMEDOUT
75.16 npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
75.16 npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
75.16 npm ERR! network 
75.16 npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
75.16 npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
75.17 
75.17 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-12-03T15_19_12_820Z-debug-0.log
------
Dockerfile:15
--------------------
  14 |     # Install node packages, install serve, build the app, and remove dependencies at the end
  15 | >>> RUN npm install \
  16 | >>>     && npm install -g serve \
  17 | >>>     && npm run build \
  18 | >>>     && rm -fr node_modules
  19 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install     && npm install -g serve     && npm run build     && rm -fr node_modules" did not complete successfully: exit code: 146
```

Я не работал ранее ни с `docker` ни с `npm` - поэтому хоть я и вижу что просит меня сделать `docker` - не понимаю где, и с помощью чего я должен это сделать.

Например:

```
55.05 npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
```

`performance.now()` и `performance.timeOrigin`. Что это? Где я должен это использовать? Код взят из github, куда я должен это вписать или где выполнить?

```
75.16 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.2.4` to update!
```

`npm install -g npm@10.2.4` - как мне ее выполнить если эту инструкцию нужно выполнять внутри контейнера (так как, как я понял, контейнер это изолированная среда и к пакетам на самой операционке не имеет никакого отношения), а контейнер не создается из-за этой самой ошибки?

В общем - **как развернуть контейнер?**

Comment: Ошибка `npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT` намекает, что во время сборки отвалился репозиторий `npm`. Пересоберите ещё раз. Я проверил минуту назад - образ собрался.